# Finding the second directive in the loop

Tags: angularjs

I have a repeater that creates 3 directives.   Each directive has its own carousel type of functionality and each has its own collection.   When the carousel of the first directive changes, I want to trigger a change in the second carousel by giving the second carousel a new collection to work with.

How do I go about finding the second mission-descendant-directive's that gets created?

```html
<div ng-repeat="mission in carouselMissions track by mission.missionDefinitionId">
    <div class="row">
        <mission-descendant-directive header="header" data-id="mission.missionDefinitionId" data-level="1" subChild="subChild.id"></mission-descendant-directive>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I would use events, do something like `$scope.emit` on the first carousel directive to notify the other ones that something has changed.

Comment: Initially, I only want to update the second directive and not the third one.  But I am not sure how to actually find that directive using code and then update it's bound collection with new data.  I suppose I can loop through DOM elements until I find what I need, was hoping for something more elengant and built in by Angular.    Then I have the issue of updating the collection and rebuilding that directive.

Comment: Why not pass the collection into directive? If the collection changes, you have to do nothing (well, maybe watch collection on directive).

Comment: Currently, the collection is built inside of the directive's code based on an id passed to the directive.  I would need to reverse this a bit to get the collection ahead of time.  But trying to think through doing something like this now.   Each directive receive's a different Id, and then a look up is done to get it's data and bind.